# Moment Generating Function of beta ( Hard )

Tags: integration, self-learning, statistical-inference, moment-generating-functions

Given $X$ is a random variable ~ $Beta ( a , b)$ distribution and 
$X$ belongs in (0,1)

Does the   (MGF ) $E[e^{tx}]$ exist **for every value of $a , b$** ?

(Mgf must **not** be equal to infinity in order to exist)

thus , is $E[e^{tx}]$ finite ?

> **Update**

what if $Beta  ( a = \frac{1}{2} , b =1 ) $

the moment generating function is calculated as below

$ M_X(t) $ = $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ =$  \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} +1)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} ) +\Gamma(1)}  \int_0^1 e^{tX} x^{\frac{1}{2}-1} (1-x)^{1-1}\ dx   $=

> After - Using Taylor series expansion 
>          &  interchanging the summation and integration of the taylor series

$ M_X(t) $ = $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k! (2k+1)}$

where k is non negative integer and $t \in \mathbb{R}$

How can I prove that this last sum is finite or infinite , is there a theorem ? 
(my math background is limited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any random variable $X$ with $|X| \leq C$ with probability $1$ we have $Ee^{tX}\leq eE^{|t||X|} \leq e^{C|t|} <\infty$ for any real number $t$. In particular, Beta random variables are bounded so their MGF's exist.

About the series $\sum \frac {t^{k}} {(k!)(2k+1)}$ just observe that $|\frac {t^{k}} {(k!)(2k+1)}| <\frac {|t|^{k}} {(k!)}$ so the series is convergent for all $t$. ($\sum \frac {|t|^{k}} {(k!)}=e^{|t|}$).

Comment: thank you , I update the question with a small answer I would really appreciate if you could tell me if we can get any assumption for the last Sum $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k! (2k+1)}$

Comment: @Pedros I have updated my answer.

Comment: Do you think there is an error with my calculations?
$ M_X(t) $ = $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ =$  \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} +1)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} ) +\Gamma(1)}  \int_0^1 e^{tX} x^{\frac{1}{2}-1} (1-x)^{1-1}\ dx   $= ${\frac{1}{2}}$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ $\int_0^1 \frac{{t^kx}^k}{k!}$ $x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ dx$ =    
$\frac{1}{2}$ $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}$ $\int_0^1 {}$ $x^{k-\frac{1}{2}} \ dx$ = $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k! (2k+1)}$ 

>Used Taylor series expansion 
   &  interchanging the summation and integration of the taylor series

Comment: @Pedros Looks fine to me.

Comment: Where C a constant ? correct? also $ eE^{|t||X|}  is  ={[eE(1)]}^{|t||X|}  $ ? where E is expectation.